# No response received once '227 Entering Passive Mode'

Tags: c++, ftp, mfc, ftp-client, filezilla

I am attempting to access an FTP server (which I have access to) via a client-side program that I'm developing. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/mkulke/ftplibpp) for all of the lower level FTP communication, which has worked well up until this point, and can access the server on a local network without issue. The problem occurs when trying the same connection via the server's public IP, which still allows my program to log in, and even `PWD` - however, for whatever reason, the code fails to receive a response upon sending the `PASV` command and immediately disconnects, with the last recorded response being the `200 Type set to A` confirmation to the previous command. My initial assumption was that this was a port forwarding issue on the server-side, but programs like FileZilla seem to be able to navigate the server without difficulty. I can see that the `PASV` command has been received by the server, and it responds appropriately with a `227 Entering Passive Mode (...)`. Is there perhaps some outgoing port rule that needs to be established, or maybe and incoming rule for the client machine?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: As requested, [here's a minimum repro program](https://pastebin.com/G0D9rKip)

```
#include "ftplib.h"

bool CFTPFileFinder::Connect(CString URL)
{
    try
    {
        CString serverName;
        CString strObject;
        INTERNET_PORT nPort;
        DWORD dwServiceType = AFX_INET_SERVICE_FTP;
        if (AfxParseURL(URL, dwServiceType, serverName, strObject, nPort))
        {
            CString connectAddress;
            connectAddress.Format("%s:%d", serverName, nPort);

            if (m_FTPLibSession->Connect((LPCTSTR)connectAddress))
            {
                if(m_FTPLibSession->Login(m_Username, m_Password))
                {
                    const int max = 1024;
                    char* pwd = static_cast<char*>(malloc(max));
                    bool test1 = m_FTPLibSession->Pwd(pwd, max);  // succeeds

                    CString OutputPath("output.txt");
                    CString SearchPath("*.*");
                    bool test2 = m_FTPLibSession->Nlst(OutputPath, SearchPath);  // fails, only when public IP

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CException* pEx)
    {
        CString str;
        LPTSTR error = str.GetBuffer(255);
        pEx->GetErrorMessage(error, 255);
        pEx->Delete();
        str.ReleaseBuffer();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: With just a link to an external library, and no code from you, it will be pretty hard to answer. Would you be able to code a small simple repro program and post it in full?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the IP of the server giving the response, either it's local or public depending on where it's being contacted from

Comment: @MartinPrikryl [FileZilla verbose log](https://pastebin.com/uM8cdA2p), [the related server log](https://pastebin.com/d3BSDxwn), and finally [the server log relating to my code](https://pastebin.com/zdXpqYVY)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl [FileZilla plain FTP verbose log](https://pastebin.com/Uv8E9y1F) and [server responce](https://pastebin.com/UddPyss3). Apologies for the obfuscation, I'll try to adequately label them from now on.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl [As requested](https://pastebin.com/kCK7MDhu), unfortunately it's not very verbose, just the commands sent to the server and its responses

Comment: What does `Nlst` return? Did you check [`LastResponse()`](https://github.com/mkulke/ftplibpp#char-lastresponse)?

Comment: That's the exact function I'm calling that leads to the `PASV` command being sent, and in turn, disconnecting

Comment: I do not understand your response. I'm asking what does `Nlst` return? `true` or `false`? + What does `LastResponse` return after `Nlst`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread, it returns `false`, with last response being `200 Type set to A`, as mentioned in my initial question.

Comment: Did you try to debug the `Nlst` function to see then it fails?

Comment: Yes, so the specific check that fails is [the readline call in readresp](https://github.com/mkulke/ftplibpp/blob/master/ftplib.cpp#L372) and [this is what the call stack looks like](https://i.imgur.com/IW2f5E5.png) (the line numbers are 6 higher due to comment lines)

Comment: Are you running FileZilla on the same server as your program? + Did you try turning of all firewalls? + Did you try using encrypted connection with your program?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, running on the same machine and other external ones. Given that this server has sensitive work-related material on it, that's not something im open to - my next try would be some sort of port scanner/packet sniffer to see if either machine's firewalls are blocking a port. I've tried using encryption in my code but the login always ends up timing out - plus FileZilla seems able to connect with plain FTP without problem.